# Where is the documentation for version 1.0 of PostgreSQL wire protocol

Tags: postgresql, documentation, protocol

The current [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/protocol.html) refers only to version 3 of the wire protocol.

However, there is the following note in the documentation:

> For descriptions of the earlier protocol versions, see previous releases of the PostgreSQL documentation

However, I can't find anything about previous versions of the wire protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is all in the Git repository, [here](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=doc/src/sgml/protocol.sgml;h=5a73ea14b579d62156ce5254c95609200c891cee;hb=b542fa1a6e838d3e32857cdfbe8aeff940a91c74) is a link to the source. You can actually read the SGML source pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the manual of older Postgres versions.

[Postgres 7.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/protocol.html) is the latest version using **frontend/backend protocol version 2.0**:

> This document describes version 2.0 of the protocol, implemented in Postgres 6.4 and later.

For **version 1.0** you have to dig up the manual for the ancient version [Postgres 6.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/6.3/c50.htm):

> This document describes the initial version-numbered protocol, designated v1.0.